# ¿Cómo abrir archivo KML con App por defecto en Android?

Tags: java, android

Cómo se puede armar un `Intent` con un archivo formato `.KML`, para así se muestre una lista de las Apps compatibles con el formato `.KML` "Keyhole Markup Language". (Google Earth, Maps Me, GPXviewer etc...)
El archivo lo tengo dentro de la carpeta `res/raw/ruta_sendero1.kml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solucionado!**
Para leer archivos xml,json de un recurso interno

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream readFileResource(int fileName) {

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(fileName);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = inputStream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            outputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Log.v("Text Data", String.valueOf(outputStream.size()));
    return outputStream;
}
```

Función para guardar un archivo en la memoria externa

```
public boolean saveExternalFile(ByteArrayOutputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
    OutputStream outputStream = inputStream;
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File myFile = new File(fullPath, fileName);

    if(myFile.exists()) myFile.delete();
    try {
        myFile.createNewFile();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        inputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Código para abrir `ruta_sendero1.kml` con alguna aplicación para visualizar KML

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = readFileResource(R.raw.ruta_sendero1);
saveExternalFile(byteArrayOutputStream, "sample2.kml");

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample2.kml");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No tiene aplicación para ver KML", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar el intent de un archivo [**KML**](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#view-based-refresh-queries) (Keyhole Markup Language), es importante tener el correcto MIME TYPE que es

> [**application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml**](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#tracking-a-point-directly-under-your-view)

Este es un ejemplo:

```
//obtiene archivo.
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mi_mapa_google_earth.kml"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//Agrega datos al intent definiendo MIME TYPE.
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"); 

//Agrega el id (placeMark).
intent.putExtra("com.google.earth.EXTRA.tour_feature_id",  "mi_tour");
//Inicia Actividad.
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Gracias, añadido a la solución.